# Netbeans GlassFish Server 4, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false , The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

My problem is that i get this message after i run any web application. example, in netbeans i create new project and chose webapplication i leave everything default i don't change the names.

then i deploy the first time it works but when i close netbeans and open it later and try to deploy the same project that was working before i get that error, no first it get stuck at "Starting GlassFish Server 4" then i stop it and redeploy and i get

```
 Starting GlassFish Server 4
 GlassFish Server 4 is running.
 In-place deployment at C:\Users\****\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web
 GlassFish Server 4, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
 C:\Users\***\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The       
 module has not been deployed.
 See the server log for details.
 BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

so this has cost me my exam because i didn't know how to deal with it, it was devastating to feel so powerless, i immediately got disorientated and before i knew it, it was time to hand in our work and i was still stuck at first task and every other task depended on the success of the first task. Anyway since then i have been deleting glassfish and reinstalling to get it to work(too bad i dint think of this during my exams, also should have focused more on practice than theory then i could have see the problem already).

have tried adding netbeans to fire wall, changing ports and some other stuff suggested by others, still no luck, result is always the same i even used a brand new virtual machine and i still get the same message when i close netbeans and reopen it later. again when i delete glassfish and reinstall it i works just fine.

here is my server log, apologies, i don't know how to make it pretty yet.
Server Log:

```
[2014-09-13T04:14:44.926+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484853] [timeMillis: 1410574484926] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:44.928+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484853] [timeMillis: 1410574484928] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.135+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484859] [timeMillis: 1410574485135] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.151+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484853] [timeMillis: 1410574485151] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.154+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484853] [timeMillis: 1410574485154] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.167+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484853] [timeMillis: 1410574485167] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.217+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484859] [timeMillis: 1410574485217] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.224+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484853] [timeMillis: 1410574485224] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.287+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484852] [timeMillis: 1410574485287] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 38ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.314+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484852] [timeMillis: 1410574485314] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.320+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484852] [timeMillis: 1410574485320] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.366+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484859] [timeMillis: 1410574485366] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.457+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1410574485457] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (10.400ms), startup services(622ms), total(11.022ms)]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.800+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1410574484859] [timeMillis: 1410574485800] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:45.801+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1410574485801] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@648c5dd5 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@1217d00b.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:48.485+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=pool-11-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1410574488485] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:48.611+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=67 _ThreadName=pool-15-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1410574488611] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:48.863+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574488863] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:48.988+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01002] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574488988] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java security manager is disabled.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:48.988+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574488988] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Entering Security Startup Service.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:48.992+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01143] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574488992] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.040+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489040] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Security Service(s) started successfully.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.189+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489189] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.197+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489197] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.202+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489202] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.223+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489223] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server server]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.226+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489226] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server __asadmin]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.418+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489418] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.418+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489418] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.663+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489663] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.666+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489666] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.907+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489907] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [moo] at [/moo]]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:49.955+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1410574489955] [levelValue: 800] [[
  moo was successfully deployed in 1.171 milliseconds.]]
[2014-09-13T04:14:50.376+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=61 _ThreadName=Thread-14] [timeMillis: 1410574490376] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://ALIENBEEST:8686/jndi/rmi://ALIENBEEST:8686/jmxrmi]]
[2014-09-13T04:15:57.253+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00092] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=113 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1410574557253] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server shutdown initiated]]
[2014-09-13T04:15:57.255+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=113 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1410574557255] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@648c5dd5 from service registry.]]
[2014-09-13T04:15:57.255+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=113 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1410574557255] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]
[2014-09-13T04:15:57.257+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00002] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=113 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1410574557257] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null]]
[2014-09-13T04:15:57.258+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00001] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=113 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1410574557258] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.]]
[2014-09-13T04:15:57.302+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=117 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1410574557302] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool]]]
```

Comment: Show the server log...

Answer (score 18):

Alright I see no one is willing to touch this with nine foot pole so i will give my solution. after many dreadful hours of searching the web, installing and uninstalling netbeans and glassfish, trying  up to 7.4 netbeans and changing to old jdk up to 7. giving up in frustration then coming back. then this idea worked.

Solution:
start netbeans, before i deploy project i got to my installation of glasfish on my pc it looks like somthing like this

C:\Users\myusername\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\bin

start:
  asadmin.bat

then in the console that open:
  start-domain
then go back to netbeans when its done
if you refresh the netbeans server you see its running
or you can go to localhost to confirm too.

to stop it:
  stop-domain

also on another machine that has windows 7 it worked just fine.

Comment: you can also start/stop glassfish from with netbeans by clicking on the server.

Comment: start/stop only worked when i had just installed or re-installed glass-fish. Anyways just like almost every other frameworks i have ever worked with for example: Yii framework, i quickly ran into other problems javaDb Related.

Comment: This worked. I had to run it as admin.

Answer (score 5):

I think I faced some related problem and I think that the solution is that you have to launch Netbeans as an admin, instead of what netbeans doesn't have the rights to modify the filesystem and launch the glassfish server. (In my case Glassfish is under Program files directory, and user management is on).

If you can try that and tell us if it worked for my it was perfect ! (and also the URL for the domain is internal to the instalation directory)

Answer (score 2):

Go to line no. 1045 in `build-impl.xml` or click on line comes after deploying the web application as error and set the `debugmode = "true"` like this:

```
"<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>"
```

after that save it and deploy the web application, it will be deployed.