# Glassfish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have problém with my glassfish with this message:

> GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
>   C:\Users\Zdeněk\Desktop\OOPRUkol3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The
>   module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)

Glasfish started via command-line. Using Netbeans 8.0.x and glassfish 4.1. Netbeans 7.0.x and Glassfish 3.1. tryed and do not work also.

Comment: The error message does not contain enough information and says "See the server log for details". Can you see an error in the server.log (in the output window in Netbeans for Glassfish) ? Please post it along with your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans GlassFish Server 4, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false , The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799671/netbeans-glassfish-server-4-deploy-connection-refused-connect-false-the-mo)