# Mysterious error with the GlassFish Server --- The module has not been deployed, why?

Tags: java, glassfish, webserver

I get this error. What is the reason? How to fix it?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--
 To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project       Properties.
 To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 and open the template in the editor.
 -->
 <html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace:

```
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at  C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\MyFirstWebApp\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\MyFirstWebApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: 
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

I get this message when I try run my first app.

Comment: As the message says: See the server log for details.

Comment: The server log can be found in <GLASSFISH_INSTALLATION>glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log. Please retry your action and post several lines from the end of this file, which may contain deployment errors.
But from connection refused it seems that Glassfish had problems to start and listen on administration port (by default 4848)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans GlassFish Server 4, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false , The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799671/netbeans-glassfish-server-4-deploy-connection-refused-connect-false-the-mo)

Comment: [There is an answer in this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799671/netbeans-glassfish-server-4-deploy-connection-refused-connect-false-the-mo), but this seems to be a common issue, [based on this NetBeans forum post](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic62743.html). You might also [try this answer, setting debug to true to get more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28248736/212224), or undeploying your app (in "Services" > GlassFish > Applications") before running again.